# Keeping UI responsive during a Thread.Sleep()

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

Background: I am writing an application that iterates through a list of servers and obtains various details about each machine. During the iteration, I need to update various controls on the form (to display a summary of the obtained information). Because it is iterating through a list, I have called a Thread.Sleep() to allow the user time to read through the information before the next machine is interrogated. Below is my code:

```
Task TestTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                foreach (String IpAddress in ServersToCheck)
                {
                    if (IpAddress != String.Empty)
                    {
                        ServerBeingCheckedLabel.Text = IpAddress;
                        if (PingServer(IpAddress) == true)
                        {
                            PingChar_Label.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                            PingChar_Label.Text = "a";
                            CheckPermissionsAreValid(IpAddress);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            PingChar_Label.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                            PingChar_Label.Text = "r";
                            PermChar_Label.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                            PermChar_Label.Text = "r";
                        }
                    }
                }
                Thread.Sleep(10000);
                this.BackColor = FormBackGroundColor;
                TestButton.Enabled = true;
                RunTimer.Enabled = true;
            }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, UiScheduler);
```

This works fine regarding updating the controls on the form, but during the Thread.Sleep() the UI locks up. Surely if the Thread.Sleep() is called on a separate task, the UI thread has remained unblocked?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Task.Delay](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.delay(v=vs.110).aspx) should suit your needs.

Change

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
```

to

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
```

and change

```
Thread.Sleep
```

to

```
await Task.Delay
```

Comment: This seems to work fine when the last details have been loaded, but doesn't seem to delay when running through items before this

Comment: Never mind, I moved the await Task.Delay() to a different position and now it seems to be working like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: @ChrisWright you are welcome. Remember to accept an answer if your question has been resolved.

Comment: I'm just waiting on the time period to pass. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 5):

If you pass the `UiScheduler` as `TaskScheduler` then that task is running on the UI thread. So yes, the UI thread is completely blocked when you call `Thread.Sleep`.

If you want to delay use `await Task.Delay(10000)` instead to delay asynchronously.

That will make the task returned from `Task.Factory.StartNew` a `Task<Task>` because it wasn't build with async-await in mind unlike `Task.Run`. To fix that use `Task.Unwrap` on the returned Task:

```
Task<Task> TestTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
{
    // ...
    await Task.Delay(10000);
    // ...
}, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, UiScheduler);

Task actualTask = TestTask.Unwrap();
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your input, unfortunately I can only mark one response as an answer :(

Answer (score 2):

use `Task.Delay` instead of `Thread.Sleep`
checkout [This](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB0QFjAAahUKEwjKjvrXlaPHAhVUBI4KHfw3BR8&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsocial.technet.microsoft.com%2Fwiki%2Fcontents%2Farticles%2F21177.thread-sleep-vs-task-delay.aspx&ei=lQnLVYrwItSIuAT875T4AQ&usg=AFQjCNGwhMkEt4NlhzZBR4EN7VuiNIpezg&sig2=kl8jVz0XechREWVvctR1kg&bvm=bv.99804247,d.c2E&cad=rja) link for more details